# capistrano deploy task failing in Yosemite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

Here is the command I'm giving to deploy my code to a server.

```
$ cap production deploy:migrations
  * executing `production'
    triggering start callbacks for `deploy:migrations'
  * executing `multistage:ensure'
  * executing `deploy:migrations'
  * executing `deploy:update_code'
    triggering before callbacks for `deploy:update_code'
  * executing `dj:stop'
  * executing "RAILS_ENV=production god stop dj"
    servers: ["xyz.com"]
connection failed for: xyz.com (ArgumentError: non-absolute home)
```

I am able to ssh into xyz.com. My capistrano version is

```
$ cap --version
Capistrano v2.5.19
```

And it is dependant on `net-ssh-2.1.3`. The ruby version is `ruby 1.9.2p290`

Read through similar questions in Stackoverflow, all seem to are suggesting a check on /etc/passwd file in the server. I checked the file and ENV['HOME'] is correctly set for the ssh user.

HOME variable in Server.

```
$ echo $HOME
/home/deploy
```

HOME has always been like this from the start. Why would it fail all of a sudden.

Anyone facing the same issue?

Comment: The only way to get this exception (`Argument error: non-absolute home`) is having `HOME` set to a path that does not start with `/`. This will cause all calls to `File.expand_path` with paths starting with `~/` to raise. Check `HOME` env variables on server and post full `deploy.rb`.

Comment: I just updated my question